# In Google Earth API: Changing view with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, radio-button, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to create an interface in which a user can choose their view using three simple HTML radio buttons.  I have managed to get the plugin to initialize with the appropriate view (determined by which radio button I select as the default), but selecting different radio buttons still doesn't do anything.  The relevant code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('ui').innerHTML =
'<div>' +
'<h2>Select View:</h2>' +
'<input type="radio" name="view" value="valley" id="valley" onclick="ge.getView().setAbstractView(\'valleyview\');"/ checked> Full Valley<br/>' +
'<input type="radio" name="view" value="takten" id="takten" onclick="ge.getView().setAbstractView(\'taktenview\');"/> Takten Ling Monastery<br/>' +
'<input type="radio" name="view" value="stupa" id="stupa" onclick="ge.getView().setAbstractView(\'stupaview\');"/> Jonang Stupa<br/>' +
'</div>' +
'<br/>';

  }

  function initCallback(instance) {
ge = instance;
ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

// add a navigation control
ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

// add some layers
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, false);
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, false);

var la = ge.createLookAt('');

if(document.getElementById('valley').checked) {
la.set(29.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977,
25, // altitude
ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
180, // heading
60, // straight-down tilt
500 // range (inverse of zoom)
);
   }else if(document.getElementById('takten').checked) {
la.set(30.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977,
25, // altitude
ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
180, // heading
60, // straight-down tilt
500 // range (inverse of zoom)
);
}else if(document.getElementById('stupa').checked) {
la.set(31.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977,
25, // altitude
ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
180, // heading
60, // straight-down tilt
500 // range (inverse of zoom)
);
}
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);    

var valleyview = ge.createLookAt('');
  valleyview.set(29.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977,
25, // altitude
ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
180, // heading
60, // straight-down tilt
500 // range (inverse of zoom)
);

   var taktenview = ge.createLookAt('');
  taktenview.set(30.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977,
25, // altitude
ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
180, // heading
60, // straight-down tilt
500 // range (inverse of zoom)
);

   var stupaview = ge.createLookAt('');
  stupaview.set(31.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977,
25, // altitude
ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
180, // heading
60, // straight-down tilt
500 // range (inverse of zoom)
);
```

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: do you mind creating a jsfiddle.net? cause your code looks somehow horrible..

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the code in each of your `onclick` handlers...

```
onclick="ge.getView().setAbstractView(\'valleyview\');"
```

The `setAbstractView` method should be passed an object the inherits from a `KmlAbstractView` such as a `KmlCamera` or `KmlLookAt` object - but you are passing it a string value.

To fix it simply remove the single quotation marks from around the parameter.

```
onclick="ge.getView().setAbstractView(valleyview);"
```

Also, I would encapsulate the functionality into a method to make the call cleaner. Something like the following.

```
var lookat = function(abstractView) {
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(abstractView);
}
```

Then your html would simply be...

```
onclick="lookat(valleyview);"
```

**EDIT :**

Looking at it you would also need to move the various views outside the initCallBack function as you can't reference the variables you create in it from outside of it...

All in all a better way to do this would be to rewrite how you are creating and setting the views to a) remove all that duplication and b) make the code clearer.  Something like the following.

```
document.getElementById('ui').innerHTML =
    '<div>' +
    '<h2>Select View:</h2>' +
    '<input type="radio" name="view" value="valley" id="valley" onclick="lookat(29.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977);"/ checked> Full Valley<br/>' +
    '<input type="radio" name="view" value="takten" id="takten" onclick="lookat(30.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977);"/> Takten Ling Monastery<br/>' +
    '<input type="radio" name="view" value="stupa" id="stupa" onclick="lookat(31.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977);"/> Jonang Stupa<br/>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<br/>';

function initCallback(instance) {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

    // add a navigation control
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

    // add some layers
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, false);
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, false);

    // only valley can be checked here so no need for the conditional logic.
    lookat(29.36890346613675, 88.0025304326977);
}

var lookat = function(lat, lng) {
    var la = ge.createLookAt('');
    la.set(lat, lng, 25, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 180, 60, 500);
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);    
}
```